# Geolocation asynchronous iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, geocoding

I would like to geolocalize in the background with a thred! But I can not, I tried scheduler, thred, operation ect ect ... but all I block the progress of the progressBar.

Comment: CLGeocoder methods are already asynchronous and run in the background.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the devices location? i.e. lat and long? Or do you want to find the name of the place where the device is?

Comment: ... and because when I startupdatelocation the progressbar stops waiting to have finished the location and then continue forward?

Answer (score 2):

I use a singleton object for the location like this...

```
@implementation LocationManager

#pragma mark - singleton method

+ (LocationManager*)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;
    __strong static id sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedObject;
}

#pragma mark - instance methods

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //if the time interval returned from core location is more than two minutes we ignore it because it might be from an old session
    if ( abs((int) [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 120) {
        self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
//    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

@end
```

Then I just need to call...

```
[[LocationManager sharedInstance] start];
```

and the singleton will start tracking location.

Than I call...

```
[[LocationManager sharedInstance] currentLocation];
```

for the current location.

You can then use this to pass into the already asynchronous methods of CLGeocoder.

You can't rely on starting the location tracking and then instantly having the location. You need to use a method like this.

Answer (score 0):

CLGeocoder is running in background.